# Generate all subset of an array bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

For an array [1,2,3,4], I want to generate [], [1,2,3,4], [1], [2], [3], [4] , [1,2] ,[1,3],[1,4], [2,3] , [2,4] ,[3,4] , [1,4] and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to this problem is to generate all the integers between 1 and 2^ - 1.  The bit pattern then represents all the combinations.

You can use bit comparisons to extract the combos:

```
with ar as (
       select  [1,2,3,4] as ar
      )
select n,
       (select array_agg(case when n & (1<<pos) <> 0
                              then ar.ar[offset(pos)]
                         end ignore nulls)
        from ar cross join
             unnest(generate_array(0, x.cnt - 1)) pos
       ) as combo
from ar cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from ar cross join
           unnest(ar.ar) x
     ) x cross join
     unnest(generate_array(1, cast(power(2, x.cnt) - 1 as int64))) n
```

Comment: i want to be able to pass any array,not just this one array [1,2,3,4]

Comment: @PinkyJoe . . . Obviously.  It works with any array up to 128 elements in size -- and long before that the number of combos would be too big to be of any practical value.

Comment: it works perfectly for even string arrays. Is there a way I can avoid the subset where it is the same as the original array ?

Comment: it will be super helpful you can take a look at this one too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483635/fewest-number-of-buckets-to-bag-elements-in-bigquery

Comment: @PinkyJoe . . . In the last `unnest()` use `- 2` rather than `- 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is follow up for **Gordon's excellent answer** [*just upvoted it :o)*], to address two issues I noticed in it

---

- it is a little too verbose with some extra joins
- it produces correct result only for data with just one row (one array)

---

```
with data as (
  select ['a','b','c','d'] as arr union all 
  select ['x', 'y', 'z']
)
select  
  (select array_agg(
    case when n & (1<<pos) <> 0 then arr[offset(pos)] end 
    ignore nulls)
   from unnest(generate_array(0, array_length(arr) - 1)) pos
  ) as combo
from data cross join 
unnest(generate_array(1, cast(power(2, array_length(arr)) - 1 as int64))) n
-- order by array_length(combo), format('%t', combo)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant ,thank you! If you are interested in a matrix type bigquery sql, please give it a try 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483635/fewest-number-of-buckets-to-bag-elements-in-bigquery

Comment: it's not like I really interested in `matrix type bigquery sql` per se :o) - but anyway - see the answer there :o)